# Web Speech API for website with ads (commercial use)

Tags: copyright, internet, advertisements, copyright-notice, licensing

I want to use Web Speech API and the code provided here (https://github.com/mdn/web-speech-api) in a website that i will put ads or it will support paid subscription (commercial use)

Am i allowed to use it commercially? I am not familiar with the licenses terms at all, but from my understanding, i am ok https://github.com/mdn/web-speech-api/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: The code provided here is not the web speech API - it is a set of demonstrations illustrating how to use the web speech API

Comment: @user253751 yes that's true. But 1) if i use my modified code of demonstrations, doesnt mean i have to follow demonstrations License? How can the demonstration be more limited that the "initial" library? 2) if i go to the original page [here] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API) i dont see any license.

Answer (score 1):

That API proclaims that it is released under the [Creative Commons Zero v1.0 Universal](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/legalcode) license. That effectively gives up or waives all rigts that would otherwise be protected by copyright, and specifically gives permission for commercial use. It says so right on the license page you linked to.